# Electron PHP | Blank window after build

Tags: php, build, electron

I am trying to convert a PHP app into Electron. I discovered gulp-connect-php and decided to use it. During the dev, everything works perfectly. After I ran the build (I use electron-builder), I get a blank window when launching the app.
Here are some extracts of main.js file.

```
// Connect local PHP server
connect = require("gulp-connect-php");
var con = connect.server({
    port: 8000,
    hostname: "127.0.0.1",
    base: 'public',
    keepalive: false,
    open: false,
    root: "/",
    stdio: "inherit"
});

// Window
app.on('ready', function() {

  // Create the browser window
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
      width: 800,
      height: 800,
      icon: 'public/images/icon/icon.png',
      frame: false,
      webPreferences: {
        plugins: true,
        nodeIntegration: true
      }
  });

  // Load
  mainWindow.loadURL("http://127.0.0.1:8000");

});
```

My app entry file is public/index.php. For this reason, the loadURL function should not load a traditional index.html file. If I replace my public/index.php file by an index.html, everything is OK after build.
Here is my package.json, if it could help.

```
{
  "name": "App",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "description": "App",
  "author": "John Doe <xyz@mail.app>",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "pack": "electron-builder --dir",
    "dist": "electron-builder"
  },
  "build": {
    "appId": "App",
    "directories": {
      "output": "build"
    },
    "dmg": {
      "contents": [
        {
          "x": 110,
          "y": 150
        },
        {
          "x": 240,
          "y": 150,
          "type": "link",
          "path": "/Applications"
        }
      ]
    },
    "linux": {
      "target": [
        "AppImage",
        "deb"
      ]
    },
    "win": {
      "target": "nsis",
      "icon": "build/icon.ico"
    }
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "custom-electron-titlebar": "^3.2.2-hotfix62",
    "electron": "^8.2.0",
    "electron-builder": "^22.4.1",
    "electron-nightly": "^10.0.0-nightly.20200330"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-connect-php": "^1.0.3"
  }
}
```

I hope you could guess what is going wrong with this!
Thanks

Comment: interesting, but first glance your not doing `(new connect()).server()` etc so it might not be starting it, be aware that package expects php to be installed on the machine its run on, also you might have sandboxing or permission issues dep on which system its run on once built/packaged

Comment: try `var con = (new connect()).server({`

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I updated with ```var con = (new connect()).server({```` but the problem is still the same. I also tried to declare a /bin with php and same result: it works before build and I get a blank window after build.